# contraction mapping coeficient

Tags: contraction-operator

I have a question concerning the definition of a [contraction mapping](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Contraction_mapping).

I have found in several books different definitions for the interval from which the constant of contraction is chosen. Some say $c \in [0,1)$ and others say  $c \in (0,1)$, without any other additional conditions. Are these two definitions equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $c=0$, we have that $d(f(x),f(y))=0$ for all $x$ and $y$. In this case, $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, so $f$ is constant. Not particularly interesting.

Answer (score 0):

$c=0$ is the trivial case, right?

It works irrespective of the space and the distance metrics.